# Class not abstract for Java? Interface Use involved

Tags: java, class, interface

I'm creating a program for a homework assignment that figures out the cost for a train trip that uses an interface:

```
Train Class:

public class Train implements MassTransit {



public void getCapacity() {

    int capacity = 100;



}//end get Capacity


public int getRoundTripCost(int leave, int return_time){
    int cost = 0;
    cost = (return_time - leave) * 100;
    return cost;


} //end getRoundtrip

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Train train = new Train();
    train.getRoundTripCost(20,25);


}//end of main method



}//end train class
```

And the MassTransit Method

```
public interface MassTransit {

public void getCapacity();
public void getRoundTripCost(int leave, int return_time);


}//end of MassTransit interface
```

When I try to compile the Train class, the errors I get is "Train.java:6: error: Train is not abstract and does not override abstract method getRoundTripCost(int,int) in MassTransit"

And

"Train.java:19: error: getRoundTripCost(int,int) in Train cannot implement getRoundTripCost(int,int) in MassTransit"

I'm a complete Java newbie, and I'm still unfamiliar with Java interfaces.  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int getRoundTripCost(int leave, int return_time){
    int cost = 0;
    cost = (return_time - leave) * 100;
    return cost;


} //end getRoundtrip
```

Above overriden method return type should be `void` not `int`. Your interface defined  method with return type `void`.

```
public void getRoundTripCost(int leave, int return_time);
```

As per [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

> An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters) and return type as an instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method.

Comment: I swear, it's always something simple.  Thank you!

Comment: @user1768884: Yes, simple one. Good luck.